# Automatically create a new sheet with data of a row in the mastersheet

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Consider I have a mastersheet with names in column A and a link in colum B, starting in row 2.

The code below, for a reason I don't understand, creates only one new sheet with the name in row 2, and sets the value of the row 3 in the newly created sheet.

I'd like that to work as followed :

- create a sheet with the name in col A
- set values of col A and col B in the newly created sheet

Can someone help me figure out what's going on ?
I read the documentation about loops and getRange but I can't figure it out..

Thank you very much

```
function createNewSheets() {
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = dataSheet.getSheetByName('mastersheet').getRange('A2:B').getValues();
  
  // Get sheet with current swimmer name:
  var sheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName(swimmerName);

  var col = values[i]; // Current row
  var swimmerName = col[0]; // swimmer name

  // Iterate through all rows of data from "mastersheet":
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {

    // Check if sheet with current swimmer name exists. If it doesn't it creates it:
    if (!sheet) {
      sheet = dataSheet.insertSheet(swimmerName);
    }
    
    // Sets current row of data to the new sheet:
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, col.length, col[0].length).setValues(col)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the columns "A" and "B" from "mastersheet" sheet.
- You want to use the values of column "A" retrieved from "mastersheet" sheet as the sheet names.
- When the sheet of the retrieved sheet name is not existing in the active Spreadsheet, you want to insert new sheet with the sheet name.
- When the new sheet is inserted, you want to copy the same row of the sheet name to the inserted sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script,

  - At `var sheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName(swimmerName)`, `swimmerName` is not declaread.

    - When `swimmerName` is not declared elsewhere, an error occurs at this line.
  - At `var col = values[i]`, `i` is not declared.
  - In the for loop,

    - the 1st index is `1`. From `getRange('A2:B')`, in this case, the values are retrieved from 3rd row.
    - `swimmerName` and `col` are not changed.
- In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the current sheet names.
  2. Retrieve the values from "mastersheet" sheet.
  3. Using the retrieved sheet names and values, the new sheets are inserted and the values are put.

When above flow is reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function createNewSheets() {
  // 1. Retrieve the current sheet names.
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = dataSheet.getSheets().map(s => s.getSheetName());

  // 2. Retrieve the values from "mastersheet" sheet.
  var masterSheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName('mastersheet');
  var values = masterSheet.getRange('A2:B' + masterSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 3. Using the retrieved sheet names and values, the new sheets are inserted and the values are put.
  values.forEach(r => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(r[0])) {
      dataSheet.insertSheet(r[0]).appendRow(r);
      sheetNames.push(r[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this sample script, `sheetNames` is growing in the loop and that is used for checking the duplicate sheet names.

#### References:

- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheetsheetname)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Very awesome explanation, I understand everything you wrote.
Still, I have a problem with the rest of my script. I previously declaret 2 formulas as variables (swimmerTable and fullName) and I had in my loop :
`sheetNames.getRange(1, 3).setFormula(swimmerTable)` and `sheetNames.getRange("J2:J50").setFormula(fullName)`. The problem is it's not working anymore.. I get an error message "TypeError: sheetNames.getRange is not a function"

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, also I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question from your replying. So in order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: No problem, thanks a lot for helping !
In the initial code, I had 2 formulas that used to work. Now they don't anymore. Where should I place them so they can work ? I declared the two formulas in the comment above between your point 2 and 3. Then I placed them in the if statement :
`values.forEach(r => {
    if (!sheetNames.includes(r[0])) {
      dataSheet.insertSheet(r[0]).appendRow(r);
      sheetNames.push(r[0]);

      sheetNames.getRange(1, 3).setFormula(swimmerTable)

      sheetNames.getRange("J2:J50").setFormula(fullName)
    }
  })`

Comment: my variables are these :   `// Imports table from link
  var swimmerTable = '=IMPORTHTML(B1;"table";4)'
  // Concatenates event with pool size
  var fullName = 'CONCATENATE(C2;" - ";D2)'`

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About your new question, I cannot still understand the goal of your new question and your issue for achieving your new question. But I would like to support you and would like to try to understand your new question. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution. So if you can give me a time to understand about your new question, I'm glad. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your new question soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this again.

Comment: I will publish it in another thread. So it's easier :)

Comment: @Bastien Soret Thank you for your response. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.